# SQL Server - CHECKSUM() ON 2005 vs 2008+ versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, checksum

I've tested the `CHECKSUM()` on SQL Server 2008, 2012, 2016:

```
SELECT ABS( CHECKSUM( 0x010006002B11E231F06C1DF20200000000000000 ) )
```

All versions return: **236465144**

I don't have SQL Server 2005, so what will be the result on this version.

I saw that the `CHECKSUM()` I'm using above only applies to version 2008+.

Will the `CHECKSUM()` from SQL Server 2005 be the same as with other versions?

Comment: Are you asking about the documentation [CHECKSUM (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? The documentation states *"THIS TOPIC APPLIES TO: SQL Server (starting with 2008)"* because SQL Server 2005(-) is no longer supported; thus the documenation does not either. The statement is even on pages like [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017); `SUM` was available way before SQL Server 2008. What's the reason behind this question? Seems like an "XY".

Comment: @Larnu Can I even call CHECKSUM() on 2005? The question is: if I run the query above, what will return.

Comment: Like you, I don't have access to a 2005 instance, however, (again) if you don't have one, why does it matter? As a different example, if you only have a 2016/2017 instance, why does it matter that `STRING_SPLIT` is only available on SQL Server 2016+, when it's not relevant to your environment(s)?

Comment: @Larnu Query will be executed on SQL Server version 2005. This is more a question for people who have access to 2005 version, just to test it...

Comment: A quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=_shUW4SFOpL3gQah7YDQBQ&q=SQL+Server+CHECKSUM%28%29+2005&oq=SQL+Server+CHECKSUM%28%29+2005&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4064.5257.0.5721.6.6.0.0.0.0.408.408.4-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.1.407...35i39k1j0i22i30k1.0.regN8pNvGvE) ([CHECKSUM Functions in SQL Server 2005](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1023/checksum-functions-in-sql-server-2005/))

Comment: @Larnu I think I need the same in param to be able to fully test it - same hardcoded query - therefore the query in the question

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21844

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I even call CHECKSUM() on 2005? The question is: if I run the
>   query above, what will return.

Yes you can call it and the result is the same.

Here is my SQL Server 2005:

[image]